# How to reformat spreadsheet tables by adding an extra column using the cell value

Tags: python

I have a system file with format like this:

```
      Col  1                      Col  2       Col  3
Row1: Employee Standard Report    
Row2: Effective Date              11/01/2023
Row3: Employee_ID                 Name         Gender
Row4: 0001                        A            F
Row5: 0002                        B            M
Row6: 0003                        C            F
```

The first two rows reflect the name of the report and the date the report run. So I'd like to remove the headers, and insert the date as one extra column to reformat it like:

```
 Employee_ID    Effective_Date             Name         Gender
 0001           11/01/2023                 A            F
 0002           11/01/2023                 B            M
 0003           11/01/2023                 C            F
```

Is there a way to extract the value for effective date and insert the date as a column?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Try to use pandas, but what is file extension?